# How can I "Delete All" from Inbox or Sent mail folder in iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

The sent items folder is about 8 GB and I need to clear it out to free up space. Is there any way to do it without selecting each individual message?

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Go to your Sent folder
> 2. Tap on the "Edit"-Button on the top right
> 3. Select the first email in your list
> 4. Hold down the "Move" button
> 5. **While you are still holding** the "Move"-Button, deselect the first E-Mail
> 6. **Put away all your fingers** from the screen and wait a few seconds
> 7. Now Mail asks you where to move **ALL** of your emails
> 8. Select the Trash-Folder
> 9. Inside the Trahs-Folder, you can delete all items at once

Comment: nice not many People know this trick ;-)

Comment: This is one of the craziest Apple easter eggs I have ever seen, when a simple delete all button would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Select the `Sent Items` folder
2. Select `Edit`
3. Select `Select All` (all the sent e-mails will be highlighted)
4. Press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key  (all the highlighted e-mails will move to the `Deleted Items` folder
5. - a) Right click on the `Deleted Items` folder
   - b) Select `Empty 'Deleted Items'` folder

Or

6. If your Outlook is set-up to automatically delete the items in the `Deleted Items` folder, they will auto delete when you close Outlook.

Comment: Where do you get “right click” on a touch screen?